# Display separate text strings each day

Tags: html, alternate

I want to display a text string, or a bit of code each day of the week for two weeks, then it will repeat. So through the days it will display Monday 1, Tuesday 1...Friday 1, Monday 2, Tuesday 2...Friday 2. Then it will revert back to Monday 1. If there is a way without using I-frame (have to spell like this so it will let me post the question) from another site then please say. I have tested out with I-frame but it never seems to work. So maybe a counter which when reaching 14 will revert to 1 again. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it with pure JavaScript using the following:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
    var today = new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth(),this.getDate());
    var dayOfYear = ((today - onejan +1)/86400000);
    return Math.ceil(dayOfYear/7)
};

var sentences = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh", "twelvth", "thirsteenth", "fourteenth"];
var date = new Date();
var day = (date.getDay()+6)%7+1;
day = day * ((date.getWeek()%2)+1);
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = sentences[day-1];
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/04wha99e/1/

Using simple JavaScript, you create an array of sentences you wish to have, and basically get the current day of the week (JavaScript Date.getDay() returns Sunday as 0, hence the workaround) and based on the week number being odd or even you multiply it by 1 on 2 getting a range of 1-14 and then return the sentence from the array (starting index 0, hence the minus 1)

The above script assumes, you have a div with the id container, where the inner html gets replaced:

```
<div id="container">
  This is where the sentence goes
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but when I put the javascript into a script tag and put the html code into my page it does not work. I tested it in a blank page so I believe it is a problem with the code, not my page.

Comment: Yes, I intended to give you the idea and components for doing it , not doing the whole task for you, however I've added a jsfiddle link to the working piece: https://jsfiddle.net/04wha99e/ Also the initial code was written without testing and was missing %2 after get week, which you should've found yourself based on the idea description I gave.

Comment: without the console log outputs: https://jsfiddle.net/04wha99e/1/
You should also make sure the javascript is loaded after there are actually elements by either putting the script after sentence container html or using window.onload with pure JS or $(document).ready() with jQuery

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have not got the hang of json yet but am still trying. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: In this example we are not using any JSON anywhere. Did you manage to get it working? If this answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry I meant javascript. But I did not mark it as accepted because it is only counting days when I go onto the site. It does not count a day if I do not go onto the site that day. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: No, It's doing exactly what you requested and is based on the calendar days. there's no way to only count the days of user's appearance on the site, with pure javascript, and will require server side scripting and database storing. The answer does everything accordingly to what you asked for. Have you even tried the code or do you understand it? It is giving you the sentence based on the calendar days with 14 day intervals, as requested..